# How do I deploy a svelte-kit app to aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, svelte, sveltekit

This is my config:

```
// import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
// import serverless from '@yarbsemaj/adapter-lambda';
// import { string } from 'rollup-plugin-string';

// /** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
// const config = {
//  // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
//  // for more information about preprocessors
//  preprocess: preprocess(),

//  kit: {
//      // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
//      target: '#svelte',
//      adapter: serverless(),
//  }
// };

// export default config;

import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import { string } from 'rollup-plugin-string';
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
//import node from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import serverless from '@yarbsemaj/adapter-lambda';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte',
        adapter: serverless(),
        
        // node({
        //  // default options are shown
        //  out: 'build',
        //  precompress: false,
        //  env: {
        //      host: 'HOST',
        //      port: 'PORT'
        //  }
        // }),
        vite: {
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
                },
            },
            plugins: [
                string({
                    include: ['**/*.md']
                }),
                resolve({
                    browser: true,
                    preferBuiltins: false,
                }),
                json(),
            ]
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

I don't know how to test the build directory output.

I get these files: http://sprunge.us/16H6sw